# Basis Representation Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Could anyone explain to me the following? It is an excerpt from a proof that a representation of $n$ in base $b$ is unique.

> Let the number of ways that $n$ can be expressed in base $b$ be $sb(n)$. If $n$ has another representation to the base $b$, then the same procedure will generate a new representation of $n−1$. Thus $sb(n)≤sb(n−1)$.

Why is $sb(n)≤sb(n−1)$?

Comment: What does $sb(n)$ mean?

Comment: It means the number of ways the representation of n with base b can be.

Comment: I thought a representation of $n$ in base $b$ was supposed to be unique?

Comment: It is but, this is a proof and using that in the proof would be circular logic.

Comment: I just don't understand why sb(n) is less than or equal to sb(n-1)

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have a map from the set $S_b(n)$ of representations of $n$ in base $b$ to the set $S_b(n-1)$, and this map is injective. Hence
$$s_b(n)=\lvert S_b(n)\rvert \le s_b(n-1)=\lvert S_b(n-1)\rvert$$
It's trivial if one of the last digits is not $0$, and can be proved by induction on the greatest length of the representations.

Comment: Could you explain in non mathematical terms please.

Comment: Do you know what an injection is?

Comment: No, sorry I'm a high school student. Is it just adding an element to a group?

Comment: OK. It rather simple: it means the correspondence is ono-to-one, i.e. distinct representations of $n$ give rise to distinct representations of $n-1$. Hence there are at least as many representations of $n-1$ as of $n$.

Comment: @Math Another way to think of it is in the following way. For every representation of n, we can get a representation for n-1. But there may be other representations of n-1 that don't come from a representation of n. At least, we can't say for sure at this point. Hence, the total number of representations of n-1 could be more than those we can get by going through n alone.